# WCF Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program on windows XP

Tags: wcf, windows-xp, invalidprogramexception

I have a windows forms application running on .NET 4 that communicates with a WCF web service. The application is compiled to run with X86 as the platform target. The application was deployed on a network of hundreds of computers, and there are only a couple, that happen to have a windows XP version installed (Microsoft Windows Embedded POSReady 2009, service pack 3 to be more precise) that launch the error "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" upon calling the constructor of the WCF proxy class object. In order to isolate the problem, I created a small console application that the only thing it does is to call the constructor of the web service proxy class, like:

ItesWebServiceClient m_webService = new ItesWebServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IItesWebService");

And the exception is then thrown:

[stacktrace output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcVxe.png)

The same console app runs on all other computers, even the ones with the same windows version.

We've already tried repairing and re-installing .Net framework on the failing computers but so far nothing fixes it. I also used the PEVerify tool to validate MSIL and ran the code in debug mode (no optimizations) as suggested on other posts.

Is there something I'm missing? could there be a key .Net framework component or hot fix that needs to be installed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that the person who was re-installing the .Net framework on the machines was always installing the .net client profile version. Uninstalling that version and installing the full .net 4 version solved it.